# Python groupby function to reorder a table of data

Tags: python

i would like to convert old table to new table. Notice I grouped by common time stamp and have columns by tagname with respective value.

Any example would be appreciated. old table below

old table
[image]

new_table

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should use `pivot_table` instead of `groupby` for this kind of situation, since you do not only want to aggregate by a certain column, but also change the columns, hence you want to pivot the table, not group it:

```
print(df.pivot_table(values='Value',index='Time',columns='Name'))
```

Generates the desired output:

```
Name              331FIC001  331FIC003
Time                                  
06-23-2020 11:48         13         11
06-23-2020 11:49         12         10
```

Comment: Then you would need to import correctly into the dataframe format with `pd.read_csv()`

Comment: I fixed the issue by specifing columns to read, now it works BUT groupby does not include duplicate VALUES of data so I want to KEEP duplicate values for the data

Comment: Please fix the data in you question to make it representative of the help you require.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways of doing this -

```
df.pivot(index='TIME',columns='NAME',values='VALUE')
```

```
Name              331FIC001  331FIC003
Time                                  
06-23-2020 11:48         13         11
06-23-2020 11:49         12         10
```

OR, since you specifically asked for groupby -

```
df.groupby(['TIME','NAME'])['VALUE'].sum().unstack()
```

```
Name              331FIC001  331FIC003
Time                                  
06-23-2020 11:48         13         11
06-23-2020 11:49         12         10
```

Comment: The above will not work if the values are then same for FIC001, I need to keep duplicate values.  The PIVOT_TABLE takes out duplicate values, I want to leave them in.  Maybe create a dummy column.

Comment: Ah your question doesn’t mention anything about duplicate values, can you edit your question to include that and an example of a duplicate as well? That would help me give you a better answer. You can use ‘’’df.groupby(['TIME','NAME'])['VALUE'].first().unstack()’’’ to not take a sum of duplicates if you need.